# Memoization Function In Kotlin

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I have an existing class with an instance method buildHierarchyUncached whose signature can be found below.

```
private fun buildHierarchyUncached(date: LocalDate): Node { ... }
```

I would like to provide a public **function** buildHiearchy that is a memoized version of buildHierarchyUncached. I can get close to what I want:

```
val buildHiearchy = Memoize<LocalDate, Node>({buildHierarchy(it)})
```

Which can be called like:

```
hierarchyService.buildHiearchy(businessDate)
```

Using:

```
class Memoize<I, O>(val func: (I) -> O): (I) -> O{
  val cache = hashMapOf<I, O>();
  override fun invoke(p1: I): O {
    return cache.getOrPut(p1, { func(p1) } )
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to declare the memoized function as a function instead of a property, which is not a huge deal, though I think it helps readability. Like this:

```
fun buildHierarchy(date: LocalDate): Node = Memoize<LocalDate, Node>({ buildHierarchyUncached(it)})
```

but that doesn't compile: "Type mismatch. Required Node. Found memoize."

Also, why doesn't this compile?

```
val buildHiearchy = Memoize<LocalDate, Node>({(date) -> buildHierarchy(date)})
```

Comment: For things that have compiler errors, it is nice to include the error message from the compiler so others can search/find this SO question.

Comment: Added the compile error I was getting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the nature of the problem, you need a class field to store your cache (the cached value or a caching object or a delegate). So you have to declare a `val` in the class somewhere, since functions can't do that.

Note that when you declare your `buildHiearchy` value, you get two things in one: you store a `Memoize<..>(..)` object in a class field and you get `invoke()` function (declared somewhere else, but still..). I know of no way you can declare a function and get the field storage with no additional syntax.

The code snippet uses outdated syntax. Fix like this (no parentheses):

```
val buildHiearchy = Memoize<LocalDate, Node>({date -> buildHierarchy(date)})
```

Comment: Elias' answer uses a closure and doesn't require a class. Your snippet does answer my secondary question but doesn't address my main question. I edited the question to make the actual question more clear. Namely, how[can] I declare the memoized funcion as a function instead of a property.

Comment: well, that's my point - you can't have such a function without a field somewhere

Answer (score 10):

The following solution works for single-argument functions. If you want to created a cached version of the function `bar` you simply declare it like this:

```
val cachedBar = makeFunctionCache({ bar(it) })
```

The implementation stores the cache in a closure so that you don't need to put it in a dedicated class:

```
fun <X, R> makeFunctionCache(fn: (X) -> R): (X) -> R {
    val cache: MutableMap<X, R> = HashMap()
    return {
        cache.getOrPut(it, { fn(it) })
    }
}
```

Comment: It was perhaps not clear from my question. But I would like to declare cachedBar as a function like: `fun cachedBar(date: LocalDate): Node = makeFunctionCache<LocalDate, Node>({ date -> bar(date)})`

Comment: Could you amend your question and explain in more detail exactly what it is you need to do? It's not clear to me why the closure solution would not work. It looks like, and works like, any other function. There are differences if the function is actually part of an interface, but more information would be useful.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Map.computeIfAbsent`

```
val map = HashMap<LocalDate, Node>()
val key = LocalDate("Jun 14, 2022")

val value = map.computeIfAbsent(key) { 
    Node("My fancy node") 
}
```

The calculation will be executed only once and stored in the `map`

Comment: Unfortunately when this is used recursively, a ConcurrentModificationException is thrown and its not that easy to work around it. But its a good start! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of @Elias'es [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35309775/603516) with function reference extensions:

```
fun <X, R> ((X) -> R).memoized(): (X) -> R {
    val cache = mutableMapOf<X, R>()
    return { cache.getOrPut(it) { this(it) } }
}

fun <X, Y, R> ((X, Y) -> R).memoized(): (X, Y) -> R {
    val cache = mutableMapOf<Pair<X, Y>, R>()
    return { x, y -> cache.getOrPut(x to y) { this(x, y) } }
}

val loadLibraryMemoized = System::loadLibrary.memoized()
val concatMemoized = String::plus.memoized()
```

Thread-safe versions for JVM platform:

```
fun <X, R> ((X) -> R).memoizedThreadSafe(): (X) -> R {
    val cache = ConcurrentHashMap<X, R>()
    return { cache.computeIfAbsent(it) { this(it) } }
}

fun <X, Y, R> ((X, Y) -> R).memoizedThreadSafe(): (X, Y) -> R {
    val cache = ConcurrentHashMap<Pair<X, Y>, R>()
    return { x, y -> cache.computeIfAbsent(x to y) { this(x, y) } }
}
```