# Kotlin Coin Change recursive functional approach

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, functional-programming

I'm trying to solve [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/) with next basic idea:

```
fun coinChange(coins: IntArray, amount: Int): Int {
    fun calc(source: Long, lvl: Int): Int =
        if (source == amount.toLong())
            lvl
        else if (source > amount)
            -1
        else
            coins
                .map { calc(source = source + it, lvl = lvl + 1) }
                .filter { it > 0 }
                .sorted()
                .firstOrNull() ?: -1


    return calc(source = 0, lvl = 0)
}
```

This algorithm looks correct, but it is very slow and fails the tests because of stack overflow. In that case I'm tried to speed up it a little bit, but now it's not working correctly:

```
fun coinChange(coins: IntArray, amount: Int): Int {
    val memoized = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()

    fun calc(source: Int, lvl: Int): Int =
        if (source == amount)
            lvl
        else if (source > amount)
            -1
        else
            memoized.getOrElse(source) {
                val evaluated = coins
                    .reversed()
                    .map { calc(source = source + it, lvl = lvl + 1) }
                    .filter { it > 0 }
                    .minOrNull() ?: -1

                memoized[source] = evaluated
                evaluated
            }

    return calc(source = 0, lvl = 0)
}
```

For input `coinChange(coins = intArrayOf(186, 419, 83, 408), amount = 6249)` it's returns `36`, but must be `20`. Would you kindly help me?

Comment: Seems like your question is algorithm related, so it would be easier to fix if you explain your approach first

Comment: @AbhinavMathur my approach is described via source code. I'm using classic "execution tree" in declarative way.

Comment: For anyone not well versed with Java/Kotlin, this is pretty ugly to read, given the fact that this is a common algorithm. Unless the incorrect answer is a result of the implementation, an algorithmic explanation would be better (that's just my opinion, other people might find this easier to read)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin (Scala and Swift too) functional programming aspect is overrated. In your code: reversed, map and filter triggers 3 loops. So it is better just to do regular for/while loop only. With each call triggering 3 loops(while it can be done by one loop), you are going to have a big performance hit. I have looked into Kotlin's memoization mechanism and I don't find one suitable for recursive function. (I would like to be pointed/educated) (this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35309775 and similar class approach do not work. I have to manually manage the cache) well, enough with my complaints, here is the solution that work managing the cache manually passing 189 / 189 tests

```
fun coinChange(coins: IntArray, amount: Int): Int {
    val cache = mutableMapOf<Pair<Int, Int>, Int>()
    fun dfs(p:Pair<Int, Int>):Int{
        cache[p]?.let{return it}
        val (idx, amount) = p
        val ans = if(amount == 0) 0
        else{
            var count = Int.MAX_VALUE
            for(i in idx until coins.size){ 
                val nxt = amount - coins[i]
                if(nxt < 0) continue
                val res = dfs(i to nxt) 
                if(res == Int.MAX_VALUE) continue
                count = Math.min(count, res + 1)
            }
            count 
        }
        cache[p] = ans
        return ans
    }
    coins.sort()
    coins.reverse()
    val ans = dfs(0 to amount)
    return if(ans != Int.MAX_VALUE) ans else -1
}
```

here is the unrequested python code. Caching is beautifully done with a simple decorator @cache

```
def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
    @cache
    def dfs(idx, target):
        if target == 0:
            return 0
        result = float('Inf')
        for i in range(idx, len(coins)):
            if target - coins[i] < 0: continue 
            result = min(result, 1 + dfs(i, target - coins[i]))
        return result
    coins.sort(reverse=True) 
    ans = dfs(0, amount)
    return -1 if ans == float('Inf') else ans
```

Here is another recursion approach with manual memoization

```
fun coinChange(coins: IntArray, amount: Int): Int { 
    val MAX:Long = Int.MAX_VALUE.toLong()
    val cache = mutableMapOf<Pair<Int, Int>, Long>()
    fun dfs(p:Pair<Int, Int>):Long{
        cache[p] ?. let{return it}
        val (idx, amount) = p
        val ans =   if(amount == 0) 0
                    else if(amount < 0 || idx == coins.size) MAX
                    else Math.min(dfs(idx + 1 to amount), 1 + dfs(idx to amount - coins[idx]))
        cache[p] = ans
        return ans
    }
    val ans = dfs(0 to amount) 
    return if(ans == MAX) -1 else ans.toInt()
}
```

and Python counter part

```
def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
    @cache
    def dfs(idx, amount):
        if amount == 0: return 0
        if amount < 0 or idx == len(coins): return float('Inf')
        return min(dfs(idx + 1, amount), 1 + dfs(idx, amount - coins[idx]))
    ans = dfs(0, amount)
    return ans if ans != float('Inf') else -1
```

well, you still might not be satisfied with these solutions, after all, you want to use the fancy Functional Programming sounding stuff. Well, here is Kotlin code using map, I have consciously avoided filter because it will need another loop.

```
fun coinChange(coins: IntArray, amount: Int): Int {
    val MAX:Long = Int.MAX_VALUE.toLong()
    val cache = mutableMapOf<Pair<Int, Int>, Long>()
    fun dfs(p:Pair<Int, Int>):Long{
        cache[p]?.let{return it}
        val (idx, amount) = p
        val ans:Long = if(amount == 0) 0
        else{ 
            (idx until coins.size).map{ i ->
                val nxt = amount - coins[i]
                if(nxt >= 0) 1 + dfs(i to nxt) else MAX 
            }.min()?:MAX
        }
        cache[p] = ans
        return ans
    }
    coins.sort()
    coins.reverse()
    val ans = dfs(0 to amount)  
    return if(ans >= MAX) -1 else ans.toInt()
}
```

Since there are more Python solutions submitted, leetcode testing is a bit more stringent for Python and the Python equivalent does not pass the TLE but you can see the one liner of map, filter, min all combined in Python list comprehension here

```
def coinChange(self, coins: List[int], amount: int) -> int:
    @cache
    def dfs(idx, tgt):
        return 0 if tgt == 0 else min([1 + dfs(i, tgt - coins[i]) for i in range(idx, len(coins)) if tgt - coins[i] >= 0], default=float('inf')) 
    coins.sort(reverse=True) 
    ans = dfs(0, amount)
    return -1 if ans == float('Inf') else ans
```